# How to force a bean request parameter to be required in Spring Rest MVC?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm using Spring 5 for a REST API and I can't get how to mark request parameters *required* so that Spring would reply `400 Bad request` instead of letting the request reach the controller method.

My methods use a bean to receive query string parameters, so `@RequestParam(required=true)` is not an option here:

```
@GetMapping(path="")
public String findAll(Filter filter) {
    // ...
}
```

A `Filter` looks like this:

```
public class Filter {

    private String id;

    private String usersId;

    private GregorianCalendar dayStart;

    private GregorianCalendar dayEnd;

    // ...

}
```

I'd like to require i.e. just `usersId` to be mandatory.

Is there anything like that or should I manually validate the input?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
@GetMapping(path="")
public String findAll(@Valid Filter filter) {
    // ...
}
```

And on your `Filter` class

```
public class Filter {

    private String id;
    @NotNull
    private String usersId;
    private GregorianCalendar dayStart;
    private GregorianCalendar dayEnd;

    // ...

}
```

You should also make sure that

- Validation is enabled
- Your bean is instantiated in such a way the validation rules are applied

Comment: Where do these annotation come from? And how do I make sure you bullet points? Do I need extra Spring configuration in my `@Configuration` class?

Comment: You can find a tutorial on bean validation here (it should answer all your 3 questions) https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation

Comment: And for a Spring MVC example https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

Comment: OK thanks. I hoped there was a simpler method (at least for `required` constraints) than explicit validation like that, leaving the latter to enforce full validation (a.k.a. business) rules, but that's fine.

Comment: The `required` from `@RequestParam` works only for the request parameter itself (so it does not apply to your situation).

Comment: I am not aware of a cleaner way of achieving this.